# Why won't the colors to these boxes change when button is clicked? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

So I've got a UIView called "cell" that that is repeating in a for loop and I've setup func makeStuffHappen() that executes when a UIButton is pressed. The function is supposed to be changing the color to the UIView.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

// STEP 1: consts and vars

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 600))
let colorButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 460, y: 560, width: 30, height: 30))
let numberOfCellsOnAxis = 6
let cellDimensions = view.frame.height / CGFloat(numberOfCellsOnAxis)
var cell = UIView()

func randomColor() -> UIColor {

    let red = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256))
    let green = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256))
    let blue = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256))

    return UIColor(red: red / 255, green: green / 255, blue: blue / 255, alpha: 1)
}

class takeAction : NSObject {

    var tapCount = 0


    @objc func makeStuffHappen() {

        cell.backgroundColor = randomColor()
        tapCount += 1
        print("gesture recognized, colors have changed \(tapCount) times!")

    }

}

let TakeAction = takeAction()


colorButton.addTarget( TakeAction, action: #selector(takeAction.makeStuffHappen), for: .touchUpInside)


// STEP 2: Setup repeating boxes on both x and y axis within view


for xAxis in 0...(numberOfCellsOnAxis - 1) {
    for yAxis in 0...(numberOfCellsOnAxis - 1) {

        cell = UIView()

        cell.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(xAxis) * cellDimensions, y: CGFloat(yAxis) * cellDimensions, width: cellDimensions, height: cellDimensions)

        cell.backgroundColor = randomColor()
        view.addSubview(cell)

    }

}

colorButton.backgroundColor = .magenta

view.backgroundColor = randomColor()
view.addSubview(colorButton)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

[image of UIView in for loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHLH7.png)

Comment: Can you describe what is happening?  One problem is that you are only storing a reference to the last box; `cell` needs to be an arrray `var cells = [UIView]()`

Comment: Your button only updates the last cell you create. What do you want to happen when the button is tapped?

Comment: Unrelated but when find yourself doing something like `for x in 0...(num - 1) {` you should change it to `for x in 0..<num {`.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm trying to have all cells created change to random colors each time the button is tapped. Thank you for the range fix!

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you! That's exactly what I'm doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you reuse your `cell` variable so in the end it is only referencing the last view you create. Therefore your button action is only updating that last view.

You need an array holding all of your views. Then in the button handler, iterate through them all and give each a new random color.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 600))
let colorButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 460, y: 560, width: 30, height: 30))
let numberOfCellsOnAxis = 6
let cellDimensions = view.frame.height / CGFloat(numberOfCellsOnAxis)
var cells = [UIView]()

func randomColor() -> UIColor {
    let red = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256))
    let green = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256))
    let blue = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256))

    return UIColor(red: red / 255, green: green / 255, blue: blue / 255, alpha: 1)
}

class TakeAction {
    var tapCount = 0

    @objc func makeStuffHappen() {
        cells.forEach { $0.backgroundColor = randomColor() }
        tapCount += 1
        print("gesture recognized, colors have changed \(tapCount) times!")
    }
}

let takeAction = TakeAction()
colorButton.addTarget(takeAction, action: #selector(takeAction.makeStuffHappen), for: .touchUpInside)

for xAxis in 0..<numberOfCellsOnAxis {
    for yAxis in 0..<numberOfCellsOnAxis {
        let cell = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(xAxis) * cellDimensions, y: CGFloat(yAxis) * cellDimensions, width: cellDimensions, height: cellDimensions))
        cell.backgroundColor = randomColor()
        view.addSubview(cell)
        cells.append(cell)    
    }
}

colorButton.backgroundColor = .magenta

view.backgroundColor = randomColor()
view.addSubview(colorButton)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```